# What is going wrong with postgresql initdb? Why is the `UTF-8` encoding not getting enforced?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1. Trying to enforce UTF8 encoding as default.

This is what I am doing.

```
service postgresql initdb -E 'UTF-8' \
               --lc-collate='en_US.UTF-8' \
               --lc-ctype=locale='en_US.UTF-8';
```

Although the initilization process goes on without any problem,

a `\l` at the `psql` prompt gives there details.

```
                             List of databases
   Name    | Owner    |Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US |
```

Why is the `UTF-8` encoding not getting enforced?

Comment: The documentation[[initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)] specifies `-E` as a shorthand. So the commend is legal.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the `-E`. What happens if you call initdb directly?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Apparently, if initdb is run through a runlevel script of the OS. This script might not pass on the parameters.
I couldn't run `initdb` directly as a superuser. gave an `initdb: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.` error. After logging in as an unprivileged user I was able to initialize the db with the proper encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If initdb is run through a run-level script of the OS. This script might not pass on the parameters.

I couldn't run `initdb` directly as a superuser. Gave an

```
initdb: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

error. After logging in as an unprivileged user I was able to initialize the db with the proper encoding.

To initilize the db, run initdb directly. The command

```
/usr/bin/initdb --pgdata=/var/lib/pgsql9/data/ -E 'UTF-8' \
--lc-collate='en_US.UTF-8' \
--lc-ctype='en_US.UTF-8';
```

was run under the non-superuser `postgres.`